# get the id of the anchor element in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, anchor

I had a div like below

```
    <div class="big_buttonsyle">
      <a id="get_a_tag_id" class="get_ids">
        <img src="/static/images/add_another_anchor_tag.png">
      </a>
    </div>

$('.get_ids').click(function(){
    var element_id = this.id
    console.log(element_id);
});
```

So from the above code, when a user clicks on anchor tag that contains the image, i should do something like replicate the div some kind of stuff.

But when i tried to print the current id, i think nothing is working can anyone please let me know how to get the id of the anchor tag when we click on Anchor tag that contains the image src as  above ?

Comment: whether your script is in a dom ready handler

Comment: yeah i wrote that in document.ready

Comment: Where is the `function() { ... }` in your code? It doesn't look like valid Javascript syntax to me.

Comment: Maybe your code misses a script tag :D

Comment: it looks fine otherwise http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3cGbF/1/

Comment: Stating the obvious but have you included jquery ? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj8Tw/)

Comment: whether the elements are created dynamically!!! try event delegation

Comment: yup thats right actually !!!! i am generating this entire `big_buttonsyle` clss div that contains image and anchor tag dynamically from jquery when we click on some button

Comment: So how to handle above case ?

Comment: Like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20261787/1636522.

Comment: yep i used like this $('form').delegate('.get_a_tag_id', 'click', function () {});

Comment: its not '.get_a_tag_id' .its '#get_a_tag_id'. you can try my code .it ll work

Comment: yeah in the present above example :) (but in my original one i had some class :))

Comment: added a fiddle in my code check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.get_ids', function () {
        var element_id = this.id
        console.log(element_id);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.get_ids').click(function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('.get_ids').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(element_id);
});
```

Makesure that you have put this in `DOM` ready.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','.get_ids',function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

adding a working fiddle to this.it is working here
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mpBn/)

Answer (score 0):

Write it when DOM gets ready:

Also, syntax of `click` function is not proper.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.get_ids').click(function(){
        var element_id = this.id
        console.log(element_id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    $(function(){
        $('.get_ids').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.get_ids').click(function(){
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id')
    console.log(element_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery attr()

```
$('.get_ids').click(function(){
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(element_id);
    console.log(element_id);
});
```